# Receiving messages sent from Google Cloud Messaging - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I am having a lot of trouble with receiving messages sent from GCM. My `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` never gets fired. I have searched around for a lot of help but of no use. Any help in this would be appreciated!

**WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("TAG", "in BroadcastReceiver");
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyGcmListenerService.class.getName());
        intent.setComponent(componentName);
        startWakefulService(context, intent);
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**IntentService**

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG = MyGcmListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyGcmListenerService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("TAG", "in HandleIntent");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("Send error: ", extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("Deleted messages: ",
                        extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                String msg = extras.getString("message");
                String urlImg = extras.getString("image");
                String title = extras.getString("title");
                Log.e("GCM Mesage: ", "msg: " + msg + " title: " + title);
                Toast.makeText(MyGcmListenerService.this, "msg: " + msg + " title: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.purepush.chatdemo">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="org.purepush.chatdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="org.purepush.chatdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".service.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="org.purepush.chatdemo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.MyGcmListenerService"/>
        <service
            android:name=".service.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".service.RegistrationIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. so there's a couple of things that need to be fixed here. First is to extends the GcmListenerService (which actually does inherit from the IntentService but does the rest of the work for you) and then to declare that it with the intent filter

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
```

Also if possible try to stick to using the GcmReceiver provided by Google which I believe inherits from WakefulBroadcastReceiver (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmReceiver).

you can find a very simple sample that I was working on at https://github.com/ucsunil/android-gcm-practice/tree/master/android-gcm-chat - a chat app (very similar to what I believe you are trying to do but then discontinued it. I remember going through the logs and I remember that it would receive the message correctly and you can use that as an example. I used the Gcm provided service and receiver.

`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mate. I have tried that documented code before trying this technique and it didn't help me. I'll check your sample chat app, maybe that will provide me with some assistance. I'll get back to you soon. Cheers

Comment: Working, now. Thanks a lot, mate!